HttpClient with .NET 8 quits when debugging
I'm attempting to use HttpClient in .NET 8 for the first time but I'm not getting it to work correctly. It's probably a small thing I'm missing but I'm struggling to figure it out.
I have an API that is internal to my company that I'm trying to hit. If I run the API in Postman, I get results as expected. However, with my current setup in code, I'm making the call and it's not getting any kind of error, but it's also not getting any data and seems like it just exits the program. It's not dropping down into the try...catch either.
I added the following NuGet package:
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting" Version="8.0.0" />

I added this code to my Program.cs file:
var workbrainApiUrl = context.Configuration["WorkbrainApiURL"] ?? string.Empty;
var workbrainClientId = context.Configuration["WorkbrainApi:Username"] ?? string.Empty;
var workbrainTransactionId = context.Configuration["WorkbrainApi:Password"] ?? string.Empty;
services.AddHttpClient("workbrainAPI", (serviceProvider, client) =>
 {
     client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
     client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
     client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Client-ID", workbrainClientId);
     client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Transaction-ID", workbrainTransactionId);                      
                                                
     client.BaseAddress = new Uri(workbrainApiUrl);
 });

This is the code I'm using to make the actual call. Again, no errors, no dropping down into the exception piece of the try...catch. Debugging, I can follow the code from Program.cs file all the way down to the call to the GetFromJsonAsync where everything seems to be correct, API URL and ClientID all populated correctly, and then it just quits. No errors or moving on past the try...catch.
try
{
    var apiEndPoint = $"service/clock/getGroupInfo?lastUpdateDate=10-02-2024" 

    var client = _factory.CreateClient("workbrainAPI");

    var response = await client.GetFromJsonAsync<ReaderGroupResponse>(apiEndPoint);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    await _log.LogError($"Error {ex.Message}");
    throw;
}

Example of response from my Postman call.
{
    "date": "Mon Nov 04 08:57:27 CST 2024",
    "result": [
        {
            "readerGroupId": 12474,
            "readerGroupName": "Southwest Group",
            "readerGroupDescription": "Used for the Southwest group",
            "readerGroupType": "CLOCK SERVER",
            "readerGroupStatus": null,
            "lastUpdateUTC": "2024-10-03 19:56:55"
        }
    ],
    "message": "Successfully Returned reader Groups.",
    "isSuccess": "true",
    "statusCode": "200 OK"
}

This is my class:
public class ReaderGroupResponse
{
    public string date { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public List<ReaderGroup> result { get; set; } = new List<ReaderGroup>();
    public string message { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public bool isSuccess { get; set; } = false;
    public string statusCode { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}

public class ReaderGroup
{
    public int ReaderGroupId { get; set; }
    public string ReaderGroupName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string ReaderGroupDescription { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string ReaderGroupType { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string LastUpdateUTC { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}


Please [edit] your question to include the findings when you check your windows event log for your application being terminated.

This shouldn't be an issue but just to give it a try,  let's add readerGroupStatus in ReaderGroup class.  May the the json parsor is acting up when it doesn't find one to one match.

?lastUpdateDate=10-02-2024" Side issue, that isn't a great date format to use.

Please share a [mcve].

Try to debug your code step by step, whether the code in the try block is executed well or not? whether the response is success? Besides, you can also try to use Fildder to capture the http request, and check is there any difference (request url, request header and response body) or error (compare with the http request send by Postman)?

Thanks for everyone's input. I decided to try using RestSharp instead of HttpClient. Still, same issue. Then researched more and found that it had to do with running it Asynchronously. Once I converted it over to Synchronous using _client.Execute(request) it worked. For this specific app I really don't need asynchronous because it's a single call. I would still be interested in know why asynchronous doesn't work but at least I can move on my application for now.

@Caverman, for the HttpClient request works synchronously but not asynchronously, I think the issue might relate the thread Pool Saturation, you can try to use  IHttpClientFactory to manage HttpClient instances efficiently.

@ZhiLv My original code was using HttpClient with IHttpClientFactory where I was seeing the issue. I would assume that RestSharp would also handle Pool Saturation but I guess I need to look in to confirming that.

There are a few ways that might help you troubleshoot this:

Check for silent application exits: in .NET if an await call encounters an unhandled exception on the same thread, it could cause the application to terminate without logging the exception. try explicitly configuring logging for unhandled exceptions.

 public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Log unhandled exceptions
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += (sender, e) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Unhandled exception: {e.ExceptionObject}");
        };

        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

builder.Logging.AddConsole().SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Debug);


Inspect the JSON response and Model: there may be an issue mapping the JSON response to ReaderGroupResponse, specifically in your model, update isSuccess to string instead of bool, as the Postman response shows "isSuccess":"true". you can also simplify the api call to isolate any JSON deserialization issues by using GetAsync instead of GetFromJsonAsync

